# how to get last dialled number in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I want last dialled number(or currently calling) programmatically from iphone. I tried

following code. but it produce a null.

```
-(NSString*)lastDialledNumber   {

    NSString *path = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mobilephone.plist";
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSString *lastDialed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict valueForKey:@"DialerSavedNumber"]];
    return (([lastDialed isEqualToString:@""])?@"":lastDialed);

}

How can I solve this?
```

Comment: can you really read the file ? i thought Apple has measures to protect users' privacy .

Comment: Even if you can read the file, I don't think this app will pass through App store review process..

Comment: i couldn't access the file. i want an alternative method to take last dialled number

Comment: Your alternative is to jailbreak your phone.  That's the only way.  You are not allowed to look at the user's private information.  Your reason doesn't matter.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with public API

Comment: Is it possible with private API?

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone call history is stored in “call_history.db” which is located at the following path:

```
/private/var/root/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db

There are other important databases on the iPhone, some of which are accessible and some are not. We can find that out using the following piece of code. This basically enumerates the system folder and subfolders and finds databases that are readable:

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath: @"/private/"]; 
NSString *nextItem = [NSString string]; 
while( (nextItem = [dirnum nextObject])) {
    if ([[nextItem pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"db"] || 
        [[nextItem pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"sqlitedb"]) { 
        if ([fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:nextItem]) { 
            NSLog(@"%@", nextItem); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Below link may help you:

```
http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/
```

Comment: but it is restricted in ios 5

Comment: @manujmv, privacy matters...I think Apple doesn't provided any public API to access call list.